# Getting the current src of an Iframe using JQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I need to get notified whenever a user clicks a link on a page in an iframe that is not from the same domain. I'm aware of xss restrictions, however all i need to know is the current page being served in the Iframe. Is there a way to do this without violating xss rules?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If not for cross-site scripting restrictions this should work. Unfortunately I don't know of a way to get the URL without violating these restrictions.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function GetIFrameUrl()
            {
                alert('url = ' + document.frames['frame1'].location.href);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="GetIFrameUrl();">Find the iFrame URL</a>
        <iframe name="frame1" src="http://www.google.com" width="100%" height="400"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it does. I don't believe there is a way to do what you need without violating the rules.

Comment: In firefox in firebug all I get is document.frames is undefined

Comment: This is a nice answer, but the asker requested a jQuery solution, not plain JavaScript.

Comment: @LS: true, but the reasonable question should be understood as "best practices way to do it with jQuery around?" ... and if this would mean to do it with plain JS it should be fine

Answer (score 40):

To get the iframe location using jQuery:

```
alert( $('iframeId').contents().get(0).location.href );
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me

Comment: this works only in the case of a same domain -- xss security prevents it for different domains

Comment: Note, if the js is running *inside* the iframe, selecting the iframe like that won't work, but selecting it like "$('iframe', window.parent.document)" does. (Still assuming the same domain.)

Answer (score 5):

You can easily do it with vanilla js.

- Query the document for an element with the specific name, id, class or whatever
- Get the source for attribute for that element

  ```
   //Get by Id
   var frame_src = document.getElementById('myIframe').src
   //Get by tag name - get the first
   var frame_src = document.getElementsByName('frmExternal')[0].src
   //Alert 
   alert(frame_src)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> // if window open in iframe then redirect to main site
         if(window.top.location != window.self.location)
         {
            alert(window.self.location);
            // top.window.location.href = window.self.location;
         }
    </script>
```