# Get the current url of iframe after redirection in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am trying to get the url of `iframe` after a redirection.

I tried below given codes

```
document.getElementById("content-preview").contentWindow.location.href;
document.frames['content-preview'].location.href;
$('iframeId').contents().get(0).location.href;
```

But none worked. All these returning the initial src url only. **The parent window and iframe are in same domain only.**

Please let me know if there is a solution for this.

I referred [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748727/getting-the-current-src-of-an-iframe-using-jquery) question to reffer.

Comment: try `document["your frame name"].location.href`

Comment: Assuming the content of the iframe is on the same domain as the parent window, what you have should work. If it's not on the same domain what you're attempting to do is not possible

Comment: @SaymoinSam, Thanks for the effort. But it is giving me error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of undefined". I am using the iframe name here

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Yeah. I saw same answer in many places. but it is giving the initial src value even after the redirect

Comment: @Arun well that's weird, here is an example in my free website it's just testing https://saymoinsam4ever.000webhostapp.com/ I'm using the same code, take a look on it, it works as expected

Comment: @SaymoinSam, I checked this. But here there is no redirection inside the iframe. The initial URL is showing. For me, I am getting the initial page url only even after an iframe internal redirection.

Comment: @Arun  ok I have updated the code to simulate that and it works

Comment: @SaymoinSam, thanks a lot for the help. Still no success with this methods. Now I am using CustomEvent - addEventListener to communicate between the iframe and parent. And passing the values. It is working fine for me

Comment: Ok, I'm glad it finally worked